# Is possible identify a journey using a link in the mail?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-tracking

I just want to know if there's a way to know which journey has sent an email, if there's anyway to track back the mail to the journey using one of the links in the mail.
Or if there might be another way to know it.
Ej.
I've received an email, how can I know, just with the mail which journey inside SFMC has sent this mail.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you view the header of the email you would be able to find something like

> x-job: 5XXXXXXX5_1XXXXXX6

Which would be the MID and JOBID of the send. You could then leverage the _job and _journey dataviews to link this to a journey